# Why would you use Windows Server Core over Linux Server?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-core

I'm doing some study for the Microsoft 70-410 exam using Plural site and in the course the instructors into a bit of depth about server core, however watching the videos it looks like just a Windows version of a Linux server OS

Why would one use Server Core over a Linux Server OS?

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting for every software that requires windows, but no graphical user interface, for example ASP or other scripts that require IIS or arbitrary win32 applications that don't require a graphical interface.

You skip a lot of overhead if you don't need the UI stuff, additionally you only need a fraction of system updates.

Additionally it saves you on license costs, compared to the other Windows Server editions.

Comment: Using your IIS example, if your doing a web server, can't Linux do that nativity a lot better than Windows?

Comment: have you ever tried running an application written in ASP on linux?

Comment: No i haven't thus why i asked

Comment: Because it's not possible. It's possible to run ASP.net on linux using mono as a .net replacement, but pure ASP only runs on IIS. But this is just an example, there are more possible applications. It boils down to "if it only runs on windows, the core server is interesting".